# Changing Table Style with VBA for multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I used the code below to change the table style of a table that is copied over from another sheet. The columns use are B-S, with Row one being headers and the rest are the table data. The rows are likely never to exceed row 1000, but if possible I want to only have the table formatted for the rows show. This will vary every time the table gets updated.

I want to change the table style for 9 different sheets, all with the same column headers, they are just divided by sheet for different departments. When I tried to repeat I ran into an error, so I am reaching out for help. Still basic VBA knowledge

```
`Sheets("Rich Baran").Select
    Range("B1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$B$1:$P:P"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table3"
    Range("Table3[#All]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"

Sheets("Jamie Lorfano").Select
    Range("B1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$B$1:P:P"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table3"
    Range("Table3[#All]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"`
```

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: @PaulCo "Select Method or Range Class Failed. It highlights the Line " ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"`" when it is used the second time

Comment: Also, if you have column B to S, why is your range up to P only? or is it intentional?

Comment: Typo on my part. The main sheet that the data is copied over from is B-S because it included a few extra calculated columbs, but the individual sheets only need to be B-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are listing a range as a table, make sure to unlist it as well.

Here is a sample code based from your code above:

```
Dim rList As Range

On Error Resume Next
With Worksheets("Jamie Lorfano")
    If .ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
        .ListObjects ("Table3")
        Set rList = .Range
        .Unlist
    End If
End With

Sheets("Jamie Lorfano").Select
    Range("B1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$B$1:P:P"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table3"
    Range("Table3[#All]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"

With Worksheets("Rich Baran")
    If .ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
        .ListObjects ("Table3")
        Set rList = .Range
        .Unlist
    End If
End With

Sheets("Rich Baran").Select
    Range("B1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$B$1:P:P"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table3"
    Range("Table3[#All]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
```

I tried the above code and is working fine for me.

Comment: I will try this. Is the unlist what will allow me to repeat this for the other sheets?

Comment: I ran it and got this message "Subscript out of range"

Comment: With Worksheets("Jamie Lorfano").ListObjects("Table3")

Comment: I updated the answer. it is due to the listobject. I added a conditional statement to check if a listobject exist

Comment: Thank you. I copied the part for the other sheets I had in the file and it worked perfect. Thanks for the help